# Sublime Text Syntax Highlighter Not working on Windows?

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, code-editor, sublime-jslint

I have created a Sublime Text File for Syntax Highlighting which is mentioned below.Its for a new Language called Visage and the Syntax definition is taken from Groovy since most of the syntax looks like Groovy.The file name is Visage.tmLanguage and can also be found on github

- [Check out the Plugin on Github](https://github.com/shivkumarganesh/VisSub/blob/master/Snippets/Visage.tmLanguage) .On Github pls navigate into the snippet folder to find the plugin.

Now when I am using it in Ubuntu 12.04 while using Sublime Text 2 it works great but when I use it in Sublime Text 2 for Windows it really does not show any syntax highlighting and rather it leaves entire thing plain black and white.I have also written snippets for this language which work real great in both the versions of sublime. Please help me to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: I added the same file to the Users folder and not the Syntax is being highlighted. I wanted to know whether there is an issue with the Permissions ?

Comment: Can't you use "Package Control" to install the plugin? It will automatically install in the correct location.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No actually this plugin is made by me itself and I was trying to use it as it is. It was there in the Packages folder and everything was working fine. But in the morning I shifted to a windows system when this happened.So I just replaced to the User folder and then opened Sublime and things worked fine.Then Again I replaced all the copied content back to Package folder still it works fine. Now I dont really know what was wrong :P ??

Answer (score 0):

My observation has been that - unlike most other plugins - syntax highlighting requires a restart of ST2 following editing of the .tmLanguage file.